# Wrapping a rake task with a before/after hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

My rails app has several custom rake tasks defined under `lib/tasks/*`

When any of these tasks run, I'd like to output a log `START` and `STOP` message.

For an individual rake task, I can do something like

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar, [:some_arg] => :some_pre_requisite do |t, args|
    Rails.logger.info "Rake START - {task: \"#{t}\", args: #{args}}"

    # Do stuff

    Rails.logger.info "Rake STOP - {task: \"#{t}\", args: #{args}}"
  end
end
```

This runs a rake task that takes an argument `:some_arg`, runs a pre-requisite task (`:some_pre_requisite`) and then runs the task. It outputs log statements before and after saying that my task has started and stopped.

If I have several dozen tasks, this gets really repetitive. I'd love to "wrap" the rake task in some other method that

- prints the `START` statement
- invokes/yields/runs the actual rake task called
- prints the `STOP` statement

I know I could set up the first print as a pre requisite and then the second print as a separate enhanced task, but that feels messy. It stores both print statements in different locations, and plus I'd have to manually `enhance` each task individually.

Any better thoughts on how this could be acheived?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

About the after hook:

```
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance do
  puts "AFTER"
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html#method-i-enhance

For the before hook (untested):

```
task :before do
  puts "BEFORE"
end

Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance(['before'])
```